# .Net WebBrowser: автоматизировать скачиваение

Tags: .net, webbrowser

Коллеги, уже четвёртый день бьюсь о стену проблемы автоматизирование скачивания файлов с сайта партнёров. Microsoft WebBrowser даёт, конечно, полный контроль над страницей, но вот оформленный редирект на скачивание из ResponseStream мне неудаётся перехватить.
Собственно страница содержит линки, в которых сидит JS, который заполняет FORM надбором параметров и сабмитит его. Вот собственно submit-редирект я могу отследить в Navigating и FileDownloaded событиях, но это всего-лишь HTML который в свою очередь уже делает ещё один редирект уже с другими параметрами и всё.. Дальше я ничего уже не могу перехватить. Зато браузер бодро "поднимает" штатное окно DownloadManager-а. Чего собственно мне и не надо.
WebClient-ом скачать не вышло потому, что нету прямого адреса к файлу, файл генерит сервер по тем самым параметрам из FORM. При этом ещё туда/сюда гуляет куча куков удостоверяющих, что я залогинен, номер сессии и ещё разные параметры.

Как быть? Работники тратят на эту работу от 4 часов в день, хотелось бы, чтобы эту работу делал за них комп, а они занимались более полезным трудом :)

Comment: попробуйте HttpWebRequest, он умеет в куки, и с редиректом тоже вроде дружит

Comment: Ну, именно этого я больше всего и боялся. Но танцы с бубном вокруг WebBrowser ни чего не дали. Собрал ВебКит на скорую руку - немного иные, но тоже - танцы с бубном.
В итоге, таки, да: HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse с глубоким изучением "общения" моего клиента с сервером в FIDDLER. 
Т.о. получился монстр "прибитый гвоздями" который тупа засылает HTTP-хидеры, читает полученные в ответ куки и так далее, пока не дотянется до всех нужных файлов и не обойдёт все 200..300 страниц списка. Очень, очень неуниверсально. Но не писатьже ради этого свой полноприводный downloader :(. Решение найдено, но...